# What is the grammatical term for "world's" here?

Tags: grammar

Is the word ***world's*** used here as an adjective or anything else? But ***dangerous*** is also an adjective here and ***the most*** is just the superlative but I can't figure out what ***world's*** is?

"The ***world's*** most dangerous criminals"

Comment: Possessive. Belonging to something. England's most famous castles, the sea's most interesting fish, the sky's brightest stars, the forest's most ancient trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "the world's most dangerous criminals" is a noun phrase consisting of a determiner ("the world's"), an adjective phrase ("most dangerous") and a noun ("criminals").

The phrase "the world's" is a determiner which is the possessive form of the noun phrase "the world". And the noun phrase "the world" consists of a determiner ("the") and a noun ("world").

Comment: The subject-determiner function of *the world's* is realized by a genitive NP (within the matrix NP *the world's most dangerous criminals*), which consists of a determinative *the* functioning as determiner, and a noun functioning as head, with the genitive marker *'s* attached to it. Whew. (Not my downvote.)